# ncftpget not working when username has a dot

Tags: ftp

I'm using ncftpget for/on 3 different ftp-servers to backup/sync the content.

Now I have a problem with a new ftp-server. The username has a dot in it: xxxxx.xxxxx. I tried to quote the username put that doesn't help. I tried -u 'xxxxx.xxxxx' and -u "xxxxx.xxxxx".

ncftpget -R -u xxxxx.xxxxx -p ######## ftp.$$$$$.$$ /mnt/backups/$$$$$ /

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: you have to escape special characters with a backslash.

xxxxx\.xxxxx'